# difference between python 2.7.3 and python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code in python 2.7.3 , i had recently using a new laptop which has python 3.3 , I don't think I should downgrade back to python 2.7.3 . The code is

:-

```
nm = input(“enter file name “)

str = raw_input(“enter ur text here: \n”)

f = open(nm,”w”)

f.write(str)

f.close()

print “1.See the file\n”

print “2.Exit\n”

s = input(“enter ur choice “)

if s == 1 :

   fi  = open(nm,”r”)

   cont  = fi.readlines()

for i in cont:

    print i

else :

    print “thank you “
```

Please tell me what are the changes i should make so that it runs easily without any error .

Comment: There are a lot of small differences. Read the book! http://python3porting.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3, use `input()` instead:

  ```
  str = input("enter ur text here: \n")
  ```
- `input()` does not evaluate the value it parses in Python 3, use `eval(input())` instead:

  ```
  s = eval(input("enter ur choice "))
  ```
- `print()` is a function in Python 3 (it was a statement in Python 2), so you have to call it:

  ```
  print("1.See the file\n")
  print("2.Exit\n")

  print(i)

  print("thank you ")
  ```

Answer (score 5):

```
raw_input()
```

becomes

```
input()
```

and

```
print " "
```

becomes

```
print()
```

Hope this helped, but more information on converting can be found at http://python3porting.com/ :)

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work properly in Python 3, always use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` since the latter function does not exist anymore. Also, the `print` statement has been replaced by a `print()` function.